# Propositional Functions with Well-Ordering/Strong Induction

Tags: induction, well-orders

I'm having trouble with this problem:

$P(k)$ is a propositional function in the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$.  $P(1)$ is true.   Further, $\forall j,k \in\mathbb{Z}(\, [P(j) \land  P(k)] \implies P(j+k)\,).$   For what elements of $\mathbb{N}$ is P(k) necessarily true?

My Thought Process:

- Well-ordering says that every non empty set of non-negative integers has a least element and that here is 1 based on domain.
- We don't have a given value for j, though we do for k.  Here is where my reasoning is breaking down.  To me, I think that using the k value and the formula without j being explicitly stated means that the conditions are true for any value j+k.  But I'm not certain.  I'd think there would need to be a 'next rung' to climb the induction ladder to say that.   If that is not the case, I'd think that it would only be strong enough to say the only element that is true is when k=1.

Comment: It is better style to use $\land$ (LaTex \land ) than ^ for "and".

Comment: Got it, edited -- thanks @DanielWainfleet

Comment: If $\neg P(k)$ for some $k\in \Bbb Z^+$ then there exists $k^* ,$ the least $k\in \Bbb Z^+$ such that $\neg P(k).$ Then $k^*>1$ because $P(1),$ so $k^*>k^*-1\in\Bbb Z.$ So $P(k^*-1)$ by the def'n of $k^*$. But then  $[P(k^*-1)\land P(1)]\implies P((k^*-1)+1)\iff P(k^*)$ contrary to $ \neg P(k^*).$

Comment: My edit was for style. Removed extra dollars so that $\forall j,k...$ et cetera would all be in one line. BTW you can use \Bbb for \mathbb, and you don't need braces {} around a single keystroke, e.g. \Bbb N. And you can use \, and \; and \quad to add space.

Comment: You're saying that you can also use the well-ordering principle to say there is a least P(k) which makes the propositional function false.   You then use that value to show how the combined statement evaluates to true, but that is contrary to what you found proceeding that.  So from that, you cannot say that any value $\textbf{necessarily true}$ other than P(1).  Unless I misinterpret what you're saying there.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet thanks for the edit for clarity and readability along with the tips for future editing.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet $\textbf{necessarily true}$ here as well means that under no state of affairs could be proposition be false right?  So based on the information shared, it could only be necessarily true for P(1)?   Maybe I don't have a precise definition down for that either.

Comment: The hypotheses imply that $\forall k\in\Bbb N\,(P(k))$ is true, because its negation, which is $\exists k\in\Bbb N\,(\neg P(k))$, leads to a contradiction, as I showed in a prior comment.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet oh man, I've been staring at this entirely too long and got lost in the sauce.  I appreciate your taking the time.

Answer (score 1):

@DanielWainfleet showed in the comments above that this is true for all k in the propositional function. He did this by contradiction

> If $\neg$P(k) for some k$\in$$\Bbb Z$$^+$ then there exists k$^∗$, the least k$\in$$\Bbb Z$$^+$ such that $\neg$P(k). Then k$^*$$\gt$1 because P(1), so $\,$ k$^*$$\gt$(k$^*$-1) $\in$$\Bbb Z$. So, P(k$ ^ *$-1) by the def'n of k$^∗$. But then [P(k$^*$-1)$\land$P(1)]$\implies$P((k$^*$-1)+1)$\Longleftrightarrow$P(k$^∗$) contrary to $\neg$P(k$^∗$).

Comment: +1. And to get to up-vote my own words. :)